# While filtering gridview from textbox show some message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` and `textbox` which is outside the gridview. I enter some text and filter records from the grid.

Now what I want is, I want to show **No Records Found** message if there are no matching records for the text inserted.

Below is my code for filtering

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearchSAP" onkeyup='FilterGrid(this);' class="field-style field-full align-none" maxlength="18" />
```

**JS Code for filter**

```
function FilterGrid(Obj) {
        var grid = document.getElementById('MainContent_grdSapDetails');
        var terms = Obj.value.toUpperCase();
        var cellNr = 0;
        var ele;
        for (var r = 1; r < grid.rows.length; r++) {
            ele = grid.rows[r].cells[cellNr].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
            if (ele.toUpperCase().indexOf(terms) >= 0)
                grid.rows[r].style.display = '';
            else grid.rows[r].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In top of your `for` loop you can check condition and  you can add Message like this

```
function FilterGrid(Obj) {
        var grid = document.getElementById('MainContent_grdSapDetails');
        var terms = Obj.value.toUpperCase();
        var cellNr = 0;
        var ele;
     if(grid.rows.length >0){
        for (var r = 1; r < grid.rows.length; r++) {
            ele = grid.rows[r].cells[cellNr].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
            if (ele.toUpperCase().indexOf(terms) >= 0)
                grid.rows[r].style.display = '';
            else grid.rows[r].style.display = 'none';
        }
       }
       else{
       alert("No Records Available);
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

on your markup, set the `EmptyDataText` property of your `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Records Found">
    <Columns>
    ......
    </Columns>
</GridView>
```

Comment: I added but it is not displaying.!. May be I need to add on JS i guess